# Android emulator works not correctly

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android Development Tool. And tried to launch simple android application but have problems with android simulator.

1. At first there was a mistake "Android emulator failed to allocate memory 8" but I fixed it reducing memory size to 512MB and now when simulator launching takes a long two -three minutes with android label shimmering. And all works too slow.

2. Second problem - emulator screen occupies almost all the screen. Checking box "scale display size to real size" didn't help.

3.And the third after successful  running of the emulator i close it and after this I can't run the emulator once again. I click on the start button and nothing happened!

How can I fix all these mistakes? How can i improve emulator performance?

Comment: The emulator does not perform well, but it sounds like you are using a netbook or something with little ram and a small screen, which will make things even worse.  You may find debugging on a device more satisfactory.

Comment: To change the `scale display size to real size` change the monitor dpi value and check the `scale` parameter right below it. You'll know how much it'll scale.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I use a powerful desktop with 8 Gb RAM and Core i7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Android Virtual Device Manager` >>> `New`>>>
[image]

And then, Create AVD.

It takes time to load the App, so be patient. 
And by the way, whenever u wanna keep testing the app, don't close the emulator, keep it open. And then whenever you DEBUG, the app will close itself automatically and re-launch.

Comment: Could you edit your answer? Your screen hide the text behind it

Comment: There is no text behind it, that was a screenshot. All I wanted you to see is THIS window. It is as simple as mentioned. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Use Intel Atom processor with VM Acceleration.

Create a new VM, and select API 15 and CPU Intel Atom x86.

You should run the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager due to activate Intel HAXM

```
<sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe.
```

More information: http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Deployment,_Testing,_and_Metrics/Configuring_the_x86_Emulator

And here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm